# ReactiveMongo ConnectionNotInitialized In Test After Migrating to Play 2.5

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest, reactivemongo, scaldi

After migrating my Play (Scala) app to 2.5.3, some tests of my code using ReactiveMongo that once passed now fail in the setup.

Here is my code using ScalaTest:

```
def fixture(testMethod: (...) => Any) {
      implicit val injector = new ScaldiApplicationBuilder()
        .prependModule(new ReactiveMongoModule)
        .prependModule(new TestModule)
        .buildInj()          
      def reactiveMongoApi = inject[ReactiveMongoApi]
      def collection: BSONCollection = reactiveMongoApi.db.collection[BSONCollection](testCollection)
      lazy val id = BSONObjectID.generate
      //Error occurs at next line
      Await.result(collection.insert(Person(id = id, slug = "test-slug", firstName = "Mickey", lastName = "Mouse")), 10.seconds)
...
}
```

At the insert line, I get this:

*reactivemongo.core.errors.ConnectionNotInitialized: MongoError['Connection is missing metadata (like protocol version, etc.) The connection pool is probably being initialized.']*

I have tried a bunch of things like initializing `collection` with a `lazy val` instead of `def`. But nothing has worked.

Any insight into how to get my tests passing again is appreciated.

Comment: You should not use `reactiveMongoApi.db` (deprecated) but `reactiveMongoApi.database`

Comment: OK. It wasn't apparent that call is deprecated since the documentation doesn't indicate that and the [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo/blob/01499f90cb0c0ddf21aa602908dc276d2f6a415b/src/main/scala/play/modules/reactivemongo/ReactiveMongoApi.scala#L47) doesn't say so either (and therefore my IDE didn't strikethrough it). But yes, that did fix it. Feel free to provide this information as an answer so I can hook you up with some points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With thanks to @cchantep, the test runs as expected by replacing this code above:

```
def collection: BSONCollection = reactiveMongoApi.db.collection[BSONCollection](testCollection)
```

with this code

```
def collection: BSONCollection = Await.result(reactiveMongoApi.database.map(_.collection[BSONCollection](testCollection)), 10.seconds)
```

In other words, `reactiveMongoApi.database` (along with the appropriate changes because of the `Future`) is the way to go.

Comment: I had this problem too, after migrate on play 2.6 and fix with this.