# Multiple Collections ReactiveMongo

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I am trying to create to multiple collections in MongoDB using ReactiveMongo driver in Play Framework.

I am using following configurations:

```
application.conf: mongodb.uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/somedb"
```

in my controllers class:

```
def userCollection = reactiveMongoApi.db.collection[BSONCollection]("user")
```

(I want to store user info in this collection). The code works fine till here. But when i try to add another collection in which i want to store form data of different format.

```
def formCollection = reactiveMongoApi.db.collection[BSONCollection("form")
```

and when i run this code, i get the following error:

**reactivemongo.core.errors.ConnectionNotInitialized: MongoError['Connection is missing metadata (like protocol version, etc.) The connection pool is probably being initialized**

How do i achieve this ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactiveMongo ConnectionNotInitialized In Test After Migrating to Play 2.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191520/reactivemongo-connectionnotinitialized-in-test-after-migrating-to-play-2-5)

Comment: You should use `.database` instead of the deprecated `.db`